# Get count of each element returned by mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, count, histogram

This is my query:

```
SELECT `Brand`,`Colour`,`Occassion`,`Fabric`,`Type` 
FROM `deals` 
WHERE `Size` 
LIKE '%XS%';
```

It returns 35 results. Now, what i want is a count of each of the columns (Brand, colour etc) which are present in the above resultset to create a histogram. I am not sure about how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define *present*. Not empty? Not `null`?

Comment: The columns have some values, if not, then it is empty.

Comment: ok, now define *values* and *empty*

Comment: Push, Are you wanting to count for example, how many DIFFERENT fabrics are present? like say cotton,poly,spandex, or are you wanting to count the AMOUNT of one type of fabric, like say 10 cottons, 12 poly?

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @RobertDickey No, I want a count of all values if each column.

Comment: @sgroves Not sure what you want to know. _values_ are anything stored in that column. By _empty_, i meant the column doesn't have a `NULL` default value.

Comment: @cerd I don't think PDO/mysqli/mysql has anything to do with it.

Comment: Dude, you can't group by more than one element (in order to `count` that element) and what you want to do here is `group` by each element (separately) in the same query... Just export it to excel and you can sum it in a sec!

Comment: @alfasin thanks, but i need it in a web app. So, you mean to say i need fire more queries in order to get the desired result. I think that is the only way.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you'd better do the counting in your code - not in the DB.

Comment: @pushpesh can you even put "nothing" into a field? wouldn't it have to contain either an empty string or `null`? that's why i said "define *empty*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ideal result should look like this:

```
$data = array(
    "Brand" => array(brand1 => 1, brand2 => 2),
    "Colour" => array(colour1 => 1, colour2 => 2),
    "Occassion" => array(Occassion1 => 1, Occassion2 => 2),
);
```

For each subarray we can draw a histogram. The code will look like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT
    `Brand`,`Colour`,`Occassion`,`Fabric`,`Type` 
FROM 
    `deals` 
WHERE
    `Size` LIKE '%XS%'";

$data = array(
    "Brand" => array(),
    "Colour" => array(),
    "Occassion" => array(),
    "Fabric" => array(),
    "Type" => array(),
    );

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value)
        {
            $data[$key][$value]++;
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Or we can define $data subarrays inside foreach to make the program more flexible:

```
$data = array();
...
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!isset($data[$key]))
        {
            $data[$key] = array();
        }
        $data[$key][$value]++;
    }
...
```

Comment: Seems like a solution. I'll try this and see if it works. Thanks for the help.